# MVC javascript relative path

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, relative-path

What would be the best way of creating relative path for JavaScript in MVC application. Since we can't use '~', '@Url.Action' in the JavaScript file. So that it can be used across the multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I always do it is to expose properties in your JavaScript file for those URLs. Then when you instantiate that code on your HTML page, allow Razor to set those properties.

In your JavaScript:

```
var Widget = function () {
    var init = function(url1, url2);

    // Do stuff

    return {
        init: init
    }
};
```

Then in your .cshtml page, do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Widget.init('@Url.Action("Method", "Controller")', '@Url.Action("Method2", "Controller")');
    // Assigning directly to the Widget object
    Widget.url3 = '@Url.Action("Method3", "Controller")';
</script>
```

Comment: The thing is I am using angularjs and in some of the page, there is no cshtml page or it can be a javascript file with html. I am thinking to use viewstart.cshtml but not sure if that is the good place to do.. Any idea?

Comment: I've done one angular project with MVC. What we did was have a utility class that would hold all of the URLs that were needed. It's the same basic setup as I have in the example, but instead of doing the links as parameters, they're assigned directly to an object property.

Comment: I found one nice article which is almost similar to Krillgar mentioned. http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2014/07/angularjs-using-relative-paths.html